# Stop Map-operation and retry later

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm writing a Hadoop Application that calculates tiles of geographic data (like google maps). When I execute a Map task, I would like to check whether the data required is available on the dfs. If it is not, the map should be executed later. I assumed I could just set the Map task as failed so that hadoop will automoatically re-execute it later. However, I can't seem to find how to do that. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map tasks will be launched only when there is data to be processed in HDFS. There is no need to check explicitly for the availability of data in the mapper code.

The number of map tasks in a job is equal to the number of the input splits or the number of blocks to be processed in case of FileInputFormat.

Would suggest to go through the appropriate MapReduce chapters in the [Hadoop - The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021773.do) for more clarity.

Comment: I was looking at my problem the wrong way. Your answer helped mee see that. Thanks.